# Prototype equivalent to jquery function without dollar

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a site with both jQuery 1.8 and Prototype 2, using $ (dollar sign) seems to call jQuery but I want to invoke Prototype (from console). Specifically to do something like this: [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106)

Ise there an Equivalent in Prototype like the jQuery() function?

Comment: Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ instead.

Comment: You must use jQuery.noconflict in order to release `$` symbol for other uses.

Comment: There is nothing in Prototype that does this, because Prototype modifies the global prototype (small p) objects in the JavaScript language to do its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype is not a single object like jQuery, so you cannot invoke it like that.

### Jquery

```
var jq = $('#id')
```

At this point you have a jQuery object that is referencing a DOM. If you try to use it like an actual DOM object, however, it won't work.

```
// This won't work
jq.className = "";
// This works because it's referencing the function inside jQuery
jq.removeClass();
```

Please note that jQuery can give you the actual DOM element if you need it, but this is not the default behavior.

### Prototype

You need to think of Prototype as making base Javascript better as opposed to an object. A great example is [Object.isUndefined](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/isUndefined/). The `Object` object already exists in Javascript, Prototype is simply extending it with another function. When you see Prototype behaving like jQuery, it's almost always because Prototype extended what was already there

```
// This is a DOM reference
var pro = $('id'); // equivalent to document.getElementById('id');
pro.className = "";
// But there's no base Prototype object so this fails
pro.isUndefined();
// This is correct
Object.isUndefined(pro);
```

Comment: so ``if (typeof object.isUndefined == 'function')`` would indicate that it's a prototype extended object :)